# Right ground connection between different blocks

Tags: power, ground, grounding, drone

Which is the right way of ground connection?

Is it necessary to separately connect grounds between different blocks, without touching other grounds? Something like ground PCB trace going through another ground polygon?

What about servo cable connection to the ESC? Signal and ground? Or signal alone?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In circuit number 2, the battery negative is not connected to the power supply that I can see ???

Comment: I am afraid that a ground isn't available on a drone.